# php foreach with inlayed html throwing errors

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am attempting to grab data from mysql using PDO and output it into a html table like so

```
  <div class="data">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <?php 
        if($_POST['submit'] && $_POST['search_for'] == "keyword") {
          $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_tbl WHERE log like '%?%' ORDER BY submission_timestamp DESC");
          foreach($stmt->execute($_POST['search_for']) as $row):
        } elseif($_POST['submit'] && $_POST['search_for'] == "address") {
          $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_tbl WHERE address like '?' ORDER BY submission_timestamp DESC");
          foreach($stmt->execute($_POST['search_for']) as $row):
        } else {
          foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM my_tbl ORDER BY submission_timestamp DESC') as $row): 
        }
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['address'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['log'] ?></td>
          <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['submission_timestamp'] ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
  </div>
```

I get an error just saying unexpected '}' right before the elseif declaration.

Although when I use

```
  <div class="data">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <?php 
          foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM my_tbl ORDER BY submission_timestamp DESC') as $row): 
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['address'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['log'] ?></td>
          <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['submission_timestamp'] ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
  </div>
```

No errors occurs and the code works as it should, grabbing data from the mysql database and displaying it a html table.

I essentially want to change the output of the table based on post data sent to the page.

Is there a way I can format the first code with the if statements similarly to the later, or should I just echo out the html in each if statement as it loops (I assume the error occurs because it is closing the foreach clause or something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="data">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <?php 
        if($_POST['submit'] && $_POST['search_for'] == "keyword") {
          $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_tbl WHERE log like '%?%' ORDER BY submission_timestamp DESC");
          $rows = $stmt->execute($_POST['search_for'];
        } elseif($_POST['submit'] && $_POST['search_for'] == "address") {
          $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_tbl WHERE address like '?' ORDER BY submission_timestamp DESC");
          $rows = $stmt->execute($_POST['search_for'];
        } else {
          $rows = $db->query('SELECT * FROM my_tbl ORDER BY submission_timestamp DESC') ;             
        }
        foreach($rows as $row): 
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['address'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['log'] ?></td>
          <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['submission_timestamp'] ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't think about putting the foreach at the end like that.

Answer (score 0):

Before you have another `foreach` statement you should end the first one.

So it would look something like this.

```
<div class="data">
<table class="table table-striped">
  <?php 
    if($_POST['submit'] && $_POST['search_for'] == "keyword") {
      $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_tbl WHERE log like '%?%' ORDER BY submission_timestamp DESC");
      foreach($stmt->execute($_POST['search_for']) as $row):
      endforeach;
    } elseif($_POST['submit'] && $_POST['search_for'] == "address") {
      $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_tbl WHERE address like '?' ORDER BY submission_timestamp DESC");
      foreach($stmt->execute($_POST['search_for']) as $row):
      //No code here?
      endforeach;
    } else {
      foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM my_tbl ORDER BY submission_timestamp DESC') as $row): 
    }
  ?>
    <tr>
      <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['address'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['log'] ?></td>
      <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['submission_timestamp'] ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm also very curious as to what Database Abstraction Layer is being used here as any I'm familiar with does not return a result set on `query` but rather returns the resource ID, with which you still need to perform the fetch on indicating the type of result set you wish to be retutned, i.e. associative array, object, etc...

Comment: I think what he's actually trying to do is use the bottom code as the body of whichever `foreach` he starts at the top.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I think it's PDO. Its statement object implements `Iterable`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes this is what I am trying to do. I was hoping I could start a foreach based on conditional statements, then the rest would fall through, then I could output my table data and end it when I am done.